# Как отключить добавленного файла от последующего добавления в commit в IntellJ

Tags: git, intellij-idea, github, git-commit

Я не особо опытный юзер с Git + IntelliJ, но хотел бы узнать как реализовать следующую вещь:
Я отправил конфигурационный файл на Git (файл с полями для добавления своих настроек, чтобы пользователю не создавать новый файл), но после отправки я хочу вставить в него на постоянной основе свои данные и отключить данный файл для дальнейшего автоматического добавления в Git, чтобы мои данные случайно не попали в репозиторий.

На данный момент я вызываю окно "Commit", убираю галку с файла и дальше нажимаю "Commit".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делать?

Вот схожая проблема в support от JetBrains: [I have .idea in gitignore, but it is still in local changes](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000001824-I-have-idea-in-gitignore-but-it-is-still-in-local-changes)

---

#### Update 1:

Как можно заметить, добавление файла в `.gitignore` не помогает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

#### Update 2

`git rm --cache <file>` - это не выход. после коммита, файл удаляется из `Git`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение достаточно неочевидное, но:

1. Открываем терминал в IntellJ
2. Удаляем локальный кэш следующей командой:

`git update-index --skip-worktree FILE_NAME`

[Ссылка на оригинал ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13631525/8992586)